# While executing below code i'm unable to see the result but while debugging i can able to execute below code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What could be wrong the with below selenium code?

In console i'm unable to see any error or exception. After executing below code i can print 0,1,2 but not able to print 3 and 4.

```
@Test(priority = 9, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
public void findSearchable() throws InterruptedException {
    
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    System.out.println("0");
    List<WebElement> searchableElements = driver
            .findElements(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("searchableElements")));
    System.out.println("1");
    List<String> searchable = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("2");
    
    for (WebElement searchableElement : searchableElements) {
        System.out.println("3");
        searchable.add(searchableElement.getText());

        System.out.println("searchable  =  " + searchable);
        System.out.println("Size of list = " + searchable.size());
    }
    System.out.println("searchableList  =  " + searchable);

    for (int i = 0; i < searchable.size() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("4");

        if ((searchable.get(i).contains(sftpCon.searchableFields("Searchable Fields", 0))) && (searchable.get(i).contains(sftpCon.searchableFields("Searchable Fields", 1)))
                && (searchable.get(i).contains(sftpCon.searchableFields("Searchable Fields", 2))) && (searchable.get(i).contains(sftpCon.searchableFields("Searchable Fields", 3)))) {
            System.out.println("Got it ...... = " + searchable.get(i));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `searchableElements` size is greater than >0 otherwise the 3&4 loops does not execute. You can print the size before the for loop that included `3` to make sure the size is greater than >0.

Comment: searchableElements Size is 14

Answer (score 0):

If you see the values when running the script in debug mode not in the normal execution mode, then please make sure the elements are loaded before getting `searchableElements`.

Change the below line

```
List<WebElement> searchableElements = driver
            .findElements(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("searchableElements")));
```

to use the webdriverwait

```
List<WebElement> searchableElements = new WebDriverWait(driver, maxTimeOut))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("searchableElements")))
//print the size here
System.out.println("Number of list items:-" + searchableElements.size());
```

Comment: after using the above code also i'm unable to  print 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

1. Now my issue has been fixed, after using below code

   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   List searchableElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("searchableElements")));